# Dataframe: Stacked Columns, Index to Field

Tags: python, dataframe, stock, yfinance

I have a dataframe of stock prices as shown in the attached screenshot. The columns are tiered, with the company being one level of column, and the price category being the next. Also, the date is the index. I would like for the company symbol to be the index, and the date to be a field (one of the columns), but I don't know where to start, and I've been struggling with this for a while. Could someone please point me in the right direction? The arrows in the attached screenshot show the manipulation I'm trying to accomplish.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8yjS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `level` argument with `stack` and `reset_index` to control the behavior you want.

example:
`x=pd.DataFrame(columns=[['a','a','b','b','c','c'],[3,4,3,4,3,4]],data=np.random.rand(3,6))`

[image]

`a, b, c` are 'company'??( I am not sure
`0, 1, 2` are date.

use `x.stack(level=0)` let only the 'company' level stack to index(row)

[image]

then, `x.stack(level=0).reset_index(level=0)`,
the `reset_index(level=0)` part let only the 'date' from index(row) to columns

[image]

you can also rename it with `x.stack(level=0).reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={'level_0':'date'})` if needed.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much! Here's the final solution:
`df.head(1).stack(level=0).reset_index(level=0).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'symbol'})`

Comment: @Mitch No worries, I'm glad to hear that :)